# Show specific properties in Select properties dialog

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to show the opened doors of a bay visualy in a SCADA widget.

So I would like to get OPEN / CLOSED state from the last triggered event, but it's not possible to select a property of an event in the "Select properties" dialog. So I can update the properties of the device each time a such event (OPEN / CLOSED) is triggered to store a specific "currentDoorState" property.

But it's also not possible to map this "custom" property to the placeholder of the svg file.

[image]

Do you plan to add the ability to select or enter a specific property in a futur version of Cumulocity? Is there a workaround to implement what I would like to do?

Comment: In SCADA widget you can access all properties of a device (managed object) but cannot access related data such as alarms, events, operations etc. You can use event processing rules to put some properties from last event into the device object and access them from SCADA widget.

Comment: I already created a rule to replicate the last event data in my device (managed object) but as said before, I can't select my custom property "currentDoorState" from the "Select properties" dialog box

Comment: I see. Originally, SCADA was designed to use any property user types into an input field but that feature was cancelled. I'm sorry. You need to contact support and make a feature request. As a workaround, you can use one of the predefined properties listed in your screenshot. Most of them don't have any meaningful functionality. e.g. Replace `currentDoorState` with one of props in the list in your rule.

Comment: Ok thanks. I also though about this work around but it's a bit dirty. I'm going to open a feature request.